# How to organize gae projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I try to find the way to organize a GAE with several projects within Eclipse using the Google plugin for GAE:

- The Web App project (a WebApp project) containing the GAE web application.
- A Java project with data access
- A Java project with utility classes

My problem here is how to link things together. I want to add the two Java projects in both  build and execution paths. Since a Web App project follows the JavaEE structure, only what is specified in the WEB-INF/lib directory is taken into account.

I would like to find out how to simulate a Jar file in this directory based on a Java project present in the Eclipse workspace based on what the Google Eclipse plugin for GAE provides.

I saw something that seems to be related in the WebApp project properties Google > Web Application, section "Suppress warnings about these build path entries being outside of WEB-INF/lib".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the GAE web application to run then you'll need the classes or a jar from the projects you want to include in the WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib folders respectively.

- One way would be to build your data and utility projects and put the resulting jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder.  You can then then reference those jars as libraries from your web app and all should be fine.  Of course that's a bit tiresome to do manually, so you should probably check out some dependency management tools.  From personal experience Ivy and IvyDE were easy to get into and should cover your needs although Maven and others have their strengths.
- Another way that is a easier (but less structured) is to used linked source folders in your build path (to the source folders for your data and utility projects).  In such way Eclipse will build those sub projects to WEB-INF/classes and build and execution should work similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark! So if I correctly understand, there is no similar support than the one from WTP where you simulate a jar in WEB-INF/lib folder for a project...

Comment: @thierrytemplier Glad it helps.  I didn't see/hear of such with GAE but if you do let me know or suggest an edit.  I recall seeing some solutions that made use of JRebel so if this is a topic still you could check that avenue.  Personally the above works fine for now and with a minimum of complexity.